# How to Add the results of a script in a html page?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello everyone and thank you for your time! I have a simple problem.. I have a javascript file and i want to embed this in a html page. Down, you will see this javascript file. At the end of this, i have this row:

```
console.log("percentage:",(counter/(data.length/4))*100)
```

This percentage i want to appear in an html file. How can i make it a script and then call it/appear it, from/in an html file?? Thank you so much in advance!My javascript file:

```
var t0= performance.now();
if (navigator.geolocation) {
var location_timeout = setTimeout("geolocFail()", 10000);

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    clearTimeout(location_timeout);

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    geocodeLatLng(lat, lng);
}, function(error) {
    clearTimeout(location_timeout);
    geolocFail();
   });
   } else {
   // Fallback for no geolocation
   geolocFail();
   }

   getBase64FromImageUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?
   location=lng,lat&size=300x300&pitch=90")

   function getBase64FromImageUrl(url) {
   var img = new Image();
   var range = 60;
   img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

   img.onload = function () {
   var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   canvas.width =this.width;
   canvas.height =this.height;

   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
   var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

   //console.log("imageData",imageData);
   //var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   var index = (150*imageData.width + 150) * 4;
   var red = imageData.data[index];
   var green = imageData.data[index + 1];
   var blue = imageData.data[index + 2];
   var alpha = imageData.data[index + 3];
   console.log(red)
   console.log(green)
   console.log(blue)
   var rangedRB = red -range;
   var rangedGB = green -range;
   var rangedBB = blue -range;

    var rangedRT = red +range;
    var rangedGT = green +range;
    var rangedBT = blue +range;

    var data = imageData.data;
    var counter = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i+=4) {
    var red = data[i];
    var green = data[i+1];
    var blue = data[i+2];
    if ((red<rangedRT && red>rangedRB) && (green<rangedGT && green>rangedGB) 
    && (blue<rangedBT && blue>rangedBB)){
    counter = counter +1;
    console.log("counter",counter)
     }
     }
     console.log("counterFinal",counter)
     console.log("data.length",data.length/4)
     console.log("percentage:",(counter/(data.length/4))*100)

     //console.log(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
     // alert(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
     var t1 = performance.now();
     console.log("The estimated time is:",t1-t0,"milliseconds")
      };

      img.src = url;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, update your script so it's encapsulated as a function. Stylistically you can choose to break it further apart, but at the very least, a function is better than having a script that operates in the global space.

```
function getGeolocationResult() {
  // script code goes here.

  return (counter / (data.length/4)*100); 
}
```

Then to embed it into an HTML page:, the most simple solution is to use Javascript, `appendChild`, and `createElement`

```
//caveat, not tested!
<html>
 <body>
  <div id='mydiv'></div>

   <script src='yourscript.js'></script>
   <script type='javascript'>
     function showPercentage() {
       var result = getGeolocationResult();
       var elm = document.getElementById('mydiv');
       var d = document.createElement('div');
       d.innerText = result;
       elm.appendChild(d);
     }

     // since you don't need to wait for the entire page to load 
     // (i.e. css and/or image tags, DOMContentLoaded should suffice. 
     // If you need to wait, use window.addEventListent('load',...) instead.
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", showPercentage);
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: Thank you! Can i appear this result as a new small window??

Comment: It doesn't appear this :(

Comment: Update your script so that it's a a function. Call that function from the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you want it to appear in the HTML. Basically you'll have an element in which you'll put the result. For example in your page you may have a `span` with id "result" and put it in there via its `innerHTML` property.

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "percentage: " + (counter/(data.length/4))*100
```

Comment: you mean that i put this: document.getelement.... in my script and this script will be in body and html code?

Comment: You'll also need to add a `<span id="result"></span>` somewhere in your page where you want the result to appear.